# Best way to call the inner most function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var f = function() {
   this.m = '10' ; 
   f1 = function(){
        alert(m)
    }
}

o = new f()
o.m

f1()
```

Is this the right way to call nested function f1 from the above example

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you wanted `f1` to be a method of `f`, in which case you need to add it as a property (as you've done for `m`):

```
var f = function() {
   this.m = '10'; 
   this.f1 = function(){
       alert(this.m); //Notice that this has changed to `this.m`
   };
}; //Function expressions should be terminated with a semicolon
```

You can then call the method on an instance of `f`:

```
o = new f();
o.f1(); //Alerts '10'
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/9GLs5/).

The way you have it currently will result in `f1` leaking into the global scope (since it's declared without the `var` statement).

---

Side note: it's usually preferrable to make your methods properties of the `prototype`. This results in a single copy of the function in memory, instead of a copy for each instance:

```
var f = function() {
   this.m = '10';
};

f.prototype.f1 = function() {
    alert(this.m);  
};
```

Comment: I agree with most of what you say, but a definition of a function with function functionName() { ... } inside another function is not leaking it into the global scope. It stays inside the scope of the other function. function i() { function o() { return 'local' } }; o() //=> error

Comment: @BeatRichartz - That's a function declaration, which will be scoped to the context in which it is declared. In the question though it's a function *expression*. The `f1` variable leaks into the global scope. The assignment happens in place, but the function will be accessible from outside that scope once it has been assigned to `f1`.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, and yes I did miss the fact that the function is assigned to an undeclared variable. But it's essentially still the same, the variable inside the function will not leak to the outside: function i() { o = function() { return 'local' } }; o() //=> error. And yes, it's bad practice to declare variables like this.

Comment: @BeatRichartz - The variable *will* leak to the global scope. The reason your example throws an error is that `o` is not a function since you haven't called `i`. The assignment happens in place. But the variable itself will be accessible.

Comment: @BeatRichartz - You're welcome :) The intricacies of scope and hoisting can be confusing sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

With your code, the function is an inner function and not callable from the outside. If you call it inside a constructor, you have to assign f1 to the object:

```
this.f1 = function() {
  alert(m);
}
```

Then you can call:

```
o = new f()
o.f1() //=> alerts 10
```

Comment: what's the diffrence between this.f1 = function(){} and f1= function(){};

Comment: With this.function, you add the function to the publicly available functions of the object. With function f1, you define an inner function of the object, which is available inside the object, but not from the outside.

Comment: @PraveenDsouza Have a look at the discussion above, I think together with the answers it displays nicely how the different assignments and your assignment work.